# Form submitting straight to root instead of specified submit page

Tags: php, apache, linux

The way it's supposed to work is that index.html submits the message directly to sendgrid.php for some reason that's not working. I've included source code of both scripts in case anyone sees any problems

**Server stats:**

> cPanel Version:   11.48.3 (build 0)
>   Apache Version:   2.2.27
>   PHP Version:  5.4.32
>   Operating System: linux

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reminderbot</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" async></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fittext/1.2/jquery.fittext.js" async></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
      .button();
  });
  </script>
<style>
body {background:#474747;}
h1 {font-family: 'Dosis', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:72pt;text-align:center;color: white;text-shadow: #000 2px 2px 2px;}
#cke_message {box-shadow: #fff 0 0 30px;margin-bottom:2%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Reminderbot</h1>
<form action="sendgrid.php" method="post"><textarea cols="50" rows="15" name="message" id="message"></textarea><center><input type="submit" value="Send" /></center></form>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'message' );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**sendgrid.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SEND REPORT</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fittext/1.2/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
h1 {
font-family: 'Dosis', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:144pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body align="center">
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    # Include the API
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'lib/SendGrid.php';
    require 'lib/SendGrid/Email.php';
    require 'lib/Smtpapi.php';
    require 'lib/Smtpapi/Header.php';
    require 'html2text.php';
    # Instantiate the client.
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid('...', '...', array("turn_off_ssl_verification" => true));
    $html = $_POST["message"];
    $text = convert_html_to_text($html);
    $date = date('l, F jS ');
    # Make the call to the client.
    $email = new SendGrid\Email();
    $email
        ->addTo('...')
        ->addTo('...')
        ->setFrom('reminderbot@exanple.com')
        ->setFromName('Reminderbot')
        ->setSubject('New reminder for ' . $date)
        ->setText($text)
        ->setHtml($html)
        ->addFilter("templates", "enabled", 1)
        ->addFilter("templates", "template_id", "...");
    $sendgrid->send($email);
    print '<h1>Sent successfully</h1>';
    ?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h1").lettering();
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem. How do you know it gets submitted to "root"?

Comment: Because my homepage loads after I click submit @JohnMcMahon

Comment: I would start by analyzing the HTTP headers that are sent/received using built-in browser dev tools or a plugin.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and run in on my server and after clicking `submit`. It does go to sendgrid.php. So I think it can be something else other than these two files. Perhaps your apache setting that redirect all errors to homepage

Comment: i don't see any problem either. is the phrase "Not working" means what really?? give us more details about the problem

Comment: So after analyzing http headers I got this:

Comment: "I got this:" - Got what?

Comment: is sendgrid.php in the same folder as index.html?

Comment: Oops... @w3d it's a 302 redirect for whatever reason. Appears to be a server error because I ftp'd same files over to a different server and it works like a charm.